Computing an integral with limit
$$
\Large\mbox{Let}\quad I_{n} =
\int_{\log\left(n\right)}^{{\rm e}^n}x^{2022}\,
{\rm e}^{-x^{9}}{\rm d}x
$$

Then compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}I_{n}$.
How i can use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem ?.

my attempt was to break this integral  in two part
$$\int_{\log\left(n\right)}^{{\rm e}^n}x^{2022}\,
{\rm e}^{-x^{9}}{\rm d}x=\left(\int_{0}^{\log\left(n\right)}x^{2022}\,
{\rm e}^{-x^{9}}{\rm d}x+\int_{\log\left(n\right)}^{{\rm e}^n}x^{2022}\,
{\rm e}^{-x^{9}}{\rm d}x\right)-\int_{0}^{\log\left(n\right)}x^{2022}\,
{\rm e}^{-x^{9}}{\rm d}x$$
now how to proove both part converge to same limit.

What have you tried? Do you know the hypotesis for the theorem you mention?

i have added my attempt

Note that $\int_0^{\infty}x^{2022}\cdot exp(-x^9)=\frac19\Gamma(\frac{2023}{9})$ (, which is very large but still finite). Now you can split the integral into the integrals $\int_0^{e^n}$ and $\int_0^{\log(n)}$ with the same integrands as before. In both cases $\frac19\Gamma(\frac{2023}{9})$ dominates these integrals and both of these will converge from below for $n\to \infty$ to $\frac19\Gamma(\frac{2023}{9})$. Changing the sign of the second integral hence leads you to the answer that $I_n$ converges to $0$ for $n\to \infty$.

$\displaystyle + 1$. Pretty clear and quite simple.

Another possible solution:
For $x \ge 0\,$, define:
$ \displaystyle f_n(x):= x^{2022}e^{-x^{9}}\chi_{[\log n,\,\, e^n]}(x)$
where $\chi$ is the indicator function. We have that $f_n$ is a sequence of Lebesgue-measurable functions, moreover $f_n \rightarrow 0\,$ pointwise everywhere and $\,\,\vert f_n (x)\vert \le x^{2022}e^{-x^{9}}\, \forall n \ge 1, \forall x\ge 0$.
Since:
$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x^{2022}e^{-x^{9}}dx < \infty$
we can apply the dominated convergence theorem and interchange the limit with the integral:
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}I_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n (x)\, dx =\int_0^\infty 0\,dx=0$
